# SSH from Mac to Ubuntu Server won't allow me to perform same commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, ssh

I have set up a Ubuntu Server on a separate computer which has Apache, PHP, MySQL, SQLite, Ruby, and Rails installed. If I am locally on the server and attempt to create a new rails application I use "rails new name_ofproject". Everything works fine and the project is created.

When I ssh from terminal to my server, I can access everything, view the files, but if I attempt to create a new rails application using the same command "rails new name_ofproject" I recieve this:

```
exists  
      exists  app/controllers
      exists  app/helpers
      exists  app/models
      exists  app/views/layouts
      exists  config/environments
      exists  config/initializers
      exists  config/locales
      exists  db
      exists  doc
      exists  lib
      exists  lib/tasks
      exists  log
      exists  public/images
      exists  public/javascripts
      exists  public/stylesheets
      exists  script/performance
      exists  test/fixtures
      exists  test/functional
      exists  test/integration
      exists  test/performance
      exists  test/unit
      exists  vendor
      exists  vendor/plugins
      exists  tmp/sessions
      exists  tmp/sockets
      exists  tmp/cache
      exists  tmp/pids
   identical  Rakefile
   identical  README
   identical  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
   identical  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
   identical  config/database.yml
   identical  config/routes.rb
   identical  config/locales/en.yml
   identical  db/seeds.rb
   identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
   identical  config/initializers/inflections.rb
   identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
   identical  config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb
overwrite config/initializers/session_store.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh]
```

I am pretty new to all of this. Any ideas or suggestions would be very helpful. I assume this may just be a permission thing. Ideally I would like to be able to ssh to my sever and perform the same tasks as if I were locally on my server.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the command had been run on that machine once before and that the files it wanted to create were already there.

You can try to reproduce that by attempting to call `rails new name_ofproject` on your local machine twice consecutively with the same project name. If it shows the same message, then I guess the soultion would probably be to delete the old files on the server machine and try again.

Comment: Yeah, that's how it appears but when I check if the files were created they're not. I ended up installing Parallels and I'm running commands right inside of Linux...everything is working great now. Thanks for the feedback!